# Create default folder locations for quick reference...with mixins?

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm not sure if this is possible to achieve with mixins specifically, but hey, that's why I'm here.

I'm a recent convert to sass, and I'm working on a site with quite long path names. e.g. 'http://mysite.com/sites/mysite.com/themes/mytheme/images...'

It can get tedious either having to type, or copy and paste this long pathname, if I'm trying to add a background image to a class. So I was really hoping there was a way to create either a mixin, or some other bit of sass goodness that would allow me to do something like the following;

```
.class_name {
    background: url(image_folder('image_name.png'));
}
```

Not only would this save me a good chunk of time, but the site I'm working on has multiple image folder locations, so if I could set up a few different folder locations it would be brilliant.

As I mentioned I'm pretty new to sass so I don't know where to start with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit more research on sass, I came across [Interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_), which provides the exact functionality I was looking for.

I'm now using it like so:

```
$image_folder: "http://mysite.com/sites/mysite.com/themes/mytheme/images";
.class_name {
    background: url(#{$image_folder}/'image_name.png');
}
```